Windows aug. 13 update broke my Ubuntu system!
Yesterday (aug. 13) I updated Windows 10 on my 8 year old MSI laptop. After a reboot I was presented with a black screen with a very tiny text saying:
"Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation
Something has gone serously wrong: SBAT self-check failed: Security Policy Violation"
Note the wrong spelling (seriously) was in the message, not me!
The only way to resort this was to disable secure boot. Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling my Ubuntu system and enable secure boot?
Note: Windows and Ubuntu are on separate SSD:s.
I've seen some answers on the web, but I did not understand how to go further.
I'm 74 years old with two strokes behind me so any explanations have to be simple.
If it's possible :-)

This is definitely not an Ubuntu problem, but a Microsoft/UEFI/"Secure Boot" problem. Just leave secure boot disabled, it's not going to matter anyway.

This happened on one of my computers as well.
If we come up with a permanent fix I will provide an answer.

Well, Microsoft made it a Ubuntu problem! After investigating the boot error message I realized it had to do with secure boot, so I disabled it and got Ubuntu working again!

The asker confirmed a solution and this question has 4 close votes already. This question is not so much about Windows as it is about Ubuntu.

Windows update may also include an update to UEFI which resets to defaults. You can just plan on turning Secure Boot off, or reinstall grub & kernel in Secure boot mode. But if proprietary video driver like nVidia, you have to set MOK, machine owner key which adds to complexity.

Happened to me today after the windows update. Ubuntu starts by default after restart and was stuck with security policy error message.
quick solution - disable the secure boot. Then should work as before

Disable secureboot, boot into ubuntu and run:
mokutil --list-sbat-revocations
 sbat,1,2024010900
 shim,2
 grub,3

Something like this will show, so sbat it's blocking shim and grub. Then run:
mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete

Reboot whitout secure boot again and check:
mokutil --list-sbat-revocations
 sbat,1,2021030218

Now nothing it's blocked, reboot, enable secureboot and all should be fine.

dual-boot:
Ubuntu: 22.04.3 LTS
windows: 10
I had the same issue after updating win10 and fixed with michael's solution.
Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 secure boot
I didn't used ubuntu 18.0
just turning off secure boot run the mokito command (with sudo) and enable grub interface if needed
(How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?)
reboot on ubuntu -> once in the grub interface restart -> enable secure boot and it's done.
